# Difficulty in getting data from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have four  tables in my DB - one, called  kursplan, 2nd table is kursplan_kurse,3rd table is kursplan_kursraum 4th table is kursplan_trainer.

The 1st table Structure: `id,club_id,Tag,Kurse_namen,from,to,Kursleiter,kursraum`

here club_id means my user id in my user table

```
id     |   club_id         |    Tag      |Kurse_namen  | Kursleiter| kursraum
____________________________________________________________________________________________
1      |         35         |     Monday |2           |2           | 4
2      |         35         |     tue    |3           |3           | 3
3      |         35         |    wen     |3           |3           | 3 
4      |         12         |    thu     |1           |2           | 4
```

The 2nd table Structure:table name[kursplan_kurse]

```
id     |    club_id    | Kurse_namen    
______________________________________
1      |         35       |     Kurse1
2      |         35       |     Kurse2
3      |        35        |     Kurse3
4      |         35       |    Kurse4
```

The 3rd table Structure:table  name[kursplan_kursraum]

```
id     |    club_id    | kursraum   
______________________________________
1      |         35        |     kursraum1
2      |         35         |    kursraum2
3      |        35         |     kursraum3
4      |         35       |    kursraum4
```

The 4thtable Structure:table name[kursplan_trainer]

```
id     |    club_id    | Kursleiter 
______________________________________
1      |         35        |     Kursleiter1
2      |         35         |    Kursleiter2
3      |        35         |    Kursleiter3
4      |         35       |  Kursleiter4
```

My select query is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `kursplan` WHERE `club_id` = '35' AND `Tag` = 'Monday' ";
```

I am geting  the result in this format

```
Kurse_namen | kursraum  |Kursleiter |
=====================================
2           | 4        |2          |
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to setup a JOIN query for get values from all 3 tables
that are 2nd,3rd,4th tables

I need the result in this format I MEAN Instead of numbers i want names

```
Kurse_namen    |   kursraum       | Kursleiter     
______________________________________________
Kurse2     |   kursraum4  |    Kursleiter2
```

Please help me.

Comment: fix up the formatting of your post, right now it's unreadable

Comment: first of all don't do a `select *.` do a `select a.field, b.field c.field` where a b and c are different table identifiers `FROM table a, table b, table c WHERE a.field=b.field` then use this to work out how to do your joins. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Well your mysql setup is bad. It would be better if your tables primary key rows are not all named 'id'. Why is 'club_id' not the primary key at all?  And please tell us the names of the tables (I think we can all count ourself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is not clear if you are having related to joins you can understand it through this sql.

```
    select t2.Kurse_namen,t3.kursraum,t4.Kursleiter
    from table2 t2,table3 t3,table4 t4,table1 t1
    where t2.club_id=t3.club_id
    and t3.club_id=t4.club_id
    and t1.club_id=t2.club_id
    and t2.club_id=35
    and t1.tag='Monday'
```

Comment: This is producing many rows where as my database has to return only one row

Answer (score 1):

Use left join for ex.

```
SELECT `TABLE2 NAME`.`FIELd NAME`, `TABLE3 NAME`.`FIELD NAME` , `TABLE4 NAME`.`FIELD NAME`
        FROM `TABLE NAME` 
        LEFT JOIN `TABLE2` 
            ON `TABLE2`.`FIELD(UNIQUE DATA EXAMPLE ID)` = `TABLE3`.`FIELD(UNIQUE DATA EXAMPLE ID)` `TABLE4 NAME`.`FIELD NAME(UNIQUE DATA EXAMPLE ID)`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT `b`.`Kurse_namen`, `c`.`kursraum`, `d`.`Kursleiter`, 
FROM `kursplan` as `a`
JOIN `kursplan_kurse` as `b` ON `b`.`id` = `a`.`Kurse_namen`
JOIN `kursplan_kursraum` as `c` ON `c`.`id` = `a`.`kursraum`
JOIN `kursplan_trainer` as `f` ON `f`.`id` = `a`.`Kursleiter`
WHERE `a`.`club_id` = '35' AND `a`.`Tag` = 'Monday'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html)s

This may be could works:
(`$query =`)

```
SELECT kursplan_kurse.Kurse_namen, kursplan_kursraum.kursraum,
kursplan_trainer.Kursleiter FROM `kursplan` 
INNER JOIN kursplan 
INNER JOIN kursplan_kursraum
INNER JOIN kursplan_trainer 
USING(club_id) WHERE `club_id` = '35' AND `Tag` = 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query would output the data you need:

```
SELECT kk.Kurse_Namen, kr.kursraum, kt.kursleiter FROM kursplan k
LEFT OUTER JOIN kursplan_kurse kk (k.Kurse_namen = kk.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN kursplan_kursraum kr (k.kursraum = kr.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN kursplan_trainer kt (k.Kursleiter = kt.id)
WHERE k.club_id = 35
AND Tag = "Monday"
```